# Bowing toward the right in Aleinu leshabei'ach

Tags: minhag, bowing-kneeling, aleinu-leshabeiach, satmar

I read in [the book *The Rebbe*](//worldcat.org/oclc/810942985) that [the Satmar Rebbe](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Teitelbaum) [ztl](/a/6317) had the custom to bow specifically toward the right at ve'anachnu kore'im but I can't find any sources to this minhag. It's certainly a kabbalistic thing but I'd like to know more about it.